# Interpolation algorithm

Tags: algorithm, interpolation

I have a question regarding how to do interpolation like following case:

[image]

There are basically two sets of data, "`o`" and "`*`". In any case one of them is known, and I am trying to get the other by doing interpolation. There are some assumptions/conditions listed below:

- p1, p2, p3....are the positions, p12, p23 are the values for the intervals that hold them. Same for d1, d2, d3 and d12, d23.
- both `o` and `*` are distributed on the common axis (x axis in this case)
- both `o` and `*` are equal-distantly distributed. Meaning

  p2-p1 = p3-p2 =  .....

  and

  d2-d1 = d3-d2 = .......
- all positions (p1, p2, p3,... d1, d2, d3.....) are known, one of the data values are known (ex. p12, and p23), the other is unknown (ex. d12, and d23).

One example:

If p12 and p23 are known, and to calculate d23, d34 and d45, we simply consider the contribution of each value weighed by their length into the other data set.

[image]

I am just wondering, in the sense of computer science  is there a efficient algorithm of interpolation for this particular setup? My intuition is because all the data are distributed with equi-distance, there should be some sorta simplification/acceleration can be done? Or anyone can point out a way so I can do some literature reading? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @btilly is right. Interpolation begins by stating the interpolation model. Assuming you're content with simple piecewise linear interpolation, then efficiency and simplicity depend on things you haven't stated. Are all the data available before the algorithm runs? If so, are the data sorted on the X-axis? If not, how are the data furnished?  Are X and Y values continuous or discrete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is take a known set of points, use that to interpolate a function, and then evaluate that interpolated function at another set of points.

This is a huge topic.  You can develop your function to be piecewise linear, piecewise polynomial, a Fourier series, using wavelet algorithms..it all comes down to what kind of underlying function you think that you are trying to represent.  And that depends on your underlying problem.

Comment: Thanks btilly. Have you read the whole post? How about the example?

Comment: @NickXTsui You need to decide what problem you're trying to solve before figuring out how to solve it correctly.  Once you've figured out how to solve it correctly, then you can worry about solving it faster.  However linear interpolation tends to be so quick to compute that performance is unlikely to be a bottleneck.